# How do I set the body height to 100% of the browser?

Tags: html, css

Here is the code [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZakNY.png) 
Pictured below, is a screen shot of my web site. In the lower-right corner you can see the dimensions of the `body` element are 1263.33 x 530:

[image]

However, my styles show that I have set the body to 100% height. How do I set the html and body height to 100% of the browser?

The main problem :
I want to send the container-container div back behind the nav bar for smooth scrolling when it attaches to the sticky bar.

Comment: where is your code snippet of the attempt made to resolve the issue at hand?

Comment: pictures aren't that helpful. post a working snippet

Comment: please don't edit your question by substituting the whole content with "I've figured it out" stuff, instead either delete the question or add your solution as an answer so it can be helpful for others

Answer (score 0):

Well, to use `height:100%` all fathers of this elements must have `100% of height` a workaround for this is set the height of this element with `100vh` it tells to the div set 100% of the viewport height.

```
html, body{
   height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
html,body{
height:100%;
margin:0;

}

div{
   background-color:blue;
   height:100%;
   }
```

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

you are being down voted because you haven't shown your code, which to be honest isn't needed in this question

The height for the body is being inherited from the height of the html tag.  So try the following in your css:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: he's being downvoted because he provided the code as an image